# How best to structure folders for python with multiple modules

Tags: python, module, directory

I have the following folder structure:

```
src. 
main.py. 
../mod_a. 
....mod_a_func.py. 
../mod_b. 
....mod_b_func.py. 
......./mod_b_helper. 
..........helper.py
```

I am going to execute main.py from src folder. main needs to call functions from modules mod_a and mod_b. In addition, mod_b needs to call a helper module that resides below it.

I have read through similar answers that are available, but not sure if any of them applies here.

I tried this code, and it worked. But, is this the right(Pythonic) way to do this? Specifically, is it possible to do this without manipulating path?

```
main.py
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

    from mod_b import mod_b_func
    from mod_a import mod_a_func

    

mod_a_func.py
    

mod_b_func.py
   from .mod_b_helper import helper
```

Comment: Cant you put all the packages on folders below src or in the same dir of `main.py`?

Comment: You could make the upper folder as a python package and import with [relative package imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).